# How to change modules name (to a more friendly one) after browserifying?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am having no problem with browserification, by the way my module is super simple. Like this:

```
//sum.js
module.exports = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

So I use the command `browserify -r ./sum | uglifyjs -c -m --output sum.min.js` and everything is ok.

If I copy paste the results in chromes console, the only way I can retrieve the sum module is by doing `var sum = require("./sum")` which I believe is not that friedly.

I would be happy if I could just `var sum = require("sum")` (without the './' part).

Is it possible? I cant seem to find anything on browserify docs.

Comment: requiring without "./" means you require a package from the "node_modules" directory. you should probably create a "lib" directory and require sum from there `var sum = require("./lib/sum")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
browserify -r ./src/HelloWorld.js:hola
```

And then in the client code simply:

```
var hola = require('hola');
```

Covered briefly in the docs and command-line help:

> ```
> --require, -r  A module name or file to bundle.require()
>                Optionally use a colon separator to set the target.
> ```